# How to set up alerts on Ganglia?

Tags: cluster-computing, monitoring, distributed-computing, ganglia

How can I set up Ganglia so that I get an email if a machine in the cluster is using, for example, greater than 95% of physical RAM?

Comment: As far as my experience with Ganglia goes, it is only capable of monitoring and recording system health parameters. It is not capable of sending alerts, at least not in the basic package (there might be some other package that uses Ganglia to do so). You probably need a more advanced tool like Nagios.

Answer (score 4):

There is Open Source project on googlecode named ganglia-alert. This tool connects the gmetad and gets the data. You can configure the rules based on your requirement for sending the alerts.

I am planning to use this tool.

http://code.google.com/p/ganglia-alert/

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/ganglia/wiki/ganglia_nagios_integration

You'll need to use nagios as your alerting system.